# Leave a binary semaphore locked

Tags: semaphore

If a process is used to initial a variable and another process uses that variable

The processes are synchronized  like this :

```
Binary_semaphore s=0;

p1() {
      int x =1 ;
      semaphore_signal_B (s);
}

p2() {
      semaphore_wait_B (s);

      int y =x+1 ;
      semaphore_signal_B (s); //<---- this line
}
```

Is the last line in p2 necessary ? knowing that p1 ,p2 and s only gonna be used once .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's wrong to signal the semaphore because it's not doing you any good and it's always better the return the variables to there initial state, which is zero for this case if I'm not wrong.